# Regarding Multiple UIPickerview

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

I have three Pickerview as it shown in the image below. I main pickerview, left pickerview, and right pickerview.

The array of main pickerview has group of names, and each name has group of units. I have made array inside array in order to show them where it belongs. But I could not do it. The array for main pivkerview apears in both thr righ and left of pickerviews.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnuFd.png)

here is my code :

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var leftPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var rightPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldLeft: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFielfRight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var equal: UILabel!

var mainPickerData = []
var leftPickerData = []
var rightPickerData = []

//yourPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "back.jpg")!)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Connect data:
    self.mainPicker.delegate = self
    self.mainPicker.dataSource = self

    self.leftPicker.delegate = self
    self.leftPicker.dataSource = self

    self.rightPicker.delegate = self
    self.rightPicker.dataSource = self

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    mainPicker.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2, theHeight/2 - 182.5)
    leftPicker.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2 - 100, theHeight/2)
    rightPicker.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2 + 100, theHeight/2)
    textFieldLeft.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2 - 90, theHeight/2 + 110)
    textFielfRight.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2 + 90, theHeight/2 + 110)
    equal.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2, theHeight/2 + 110)



    let Area = ["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"]

    let Energy = ["Btus", "Calories", "Ergs", "Foot-Pounds", "Joules", "Kilogram-Calories", "Kilogram-Meters", "Kilowatt-Hours", "Newton-Meters", "Watt-Hours"]

    let Length = ["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter"]

    let Power = ["Btus/Minute", "Foot-Pounds/Min", "Foot-Pounds/Sec", "Horsepower", "Kilowatts", "Watts"]

    let Pressure = ["Pounds/Sqr Ft", "Pounds/Sqr In", "Atmospheres", "Bars", "In of Mercury", "Cm of Mercury", "Kilograms/Sqr Meter", "Pascals"]

    let Speed = ["Knots", "Miles/Hr", "Miles/Min", "Feet/Min", "Feet/Sec", "Kilometers/Hr", "Kilometer/Min", "Meters/Sec"]

    let Temperature = ["Celsius C˚", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]

    let Time = ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds", "Millisconds", "Microseconds", " Nanoseconds"]

    let Volume = ["Cupic Feet","Cubic Meter", "Gallon (Imp)", "Gallon (US)", "Quart (US)", "Pint (US)", "Fluid Oz", "Cup", "Tablespoon", "Teaspoon", "Dram (US)", "Liter"]

    let Weight = ["Short Ton (US)","Long Ton (UK)", "Pound (U.S)", "Ounce (US)", "Stone", "Metric Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram"]

    // Pickerview at the center top side of Screen.
    mainPickerData = ["Area", "Energy", "Length", "Power", "Pressure", "Speed", "Temperature", "Time", "Volume", "Weight"]

    // Pickerview at the lower left side of Screen.
    leftPickerData = [["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"], ["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"], ["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter"], ["Btus/Minute", "Foot-Pounds/Min", "Foot-Pounds/Sec", "Horsepower", "Kilowatts", "Watts"], ["Pounds/Sqr Ft", "Pounds/Sqr In", "Atmospheres", "Bars", "In of Mercury", "Cm of Mercury", "Kilograms/Sqr Meter", "Pascals"], ["Knots", "Miles/Hr", "Miles/Min", "Feet/Min", "Feet/Sec", "Kilometers/Hr", "Kilometer/Min", "Meters/Sec"],["Celsius C˚", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"], ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds", "Millisconds", "Microseconds", " Nanoseconds"], ["Cupic Feet","Cubic Meter", "Gallon (Imp)", "Gallon (US)", "Quart (US)", "Pint (US)", "Fluid Oz", "Cup", "Tablespoon", "Teaspoon", "Dram (US)", "Liter"], ["Short Ton (US)","Long Ton (UK)", "Pound (U.S)", "Ounce (US)", "Stone", "Metric Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram"]]

    // Pickerview at the lower Right side of Screen.
    rightPickerData = [["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"], ["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"], ["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter"], ["Btus/Minute", "Foot-Pounds/Min", "Foot-Pounds/Sec", "Horsepower", "Kilowatts", "Watts"], ["Pounds/Sqr Ft", "Pounds/Sqr In", "Atmospheres", "Bars", "In of Mercury", "Cm of Mercury", "Kilograms/Sqr Meter", "Pascals"], ["Knots", "Miles/Hr", "Miles/Min", "Feet/Min", "Feet/Sec", "Kilometers/Hr", "Kilometer/Min", "Meters/Sec"],["Celsius C˚", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"], ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds", "Millisconds", "Microseconds", " Nanoseconds"], ["Cupic Feet","Cubic Meter", "Gallon (Imp)", "Gallon (US)", "Quart (US)", "Pint (US)", "Fluid Oz", "Cup", "Tablespoon", "Teaspoon", "Dram (US)", "Liter"], ["Short Ton (US)","Long Ton (UK)", "Pound (U.S)", "Ounce (US)", "Stone", "Metric Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram"]]
}

// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if mainPicker.tag == 1 {

        return mainPickerData.count

    }else if leftPicker.tag == 2 {

        return leftPickerData.count

    }else{

        return rightPickerData.count
    }
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if mainPicker.tag == 1 {

        return mainPickerData[row] as? String
    }else if leftPicker.tag == 2 {

        return leftPickerData[row] as? String

    }else{

        return rightPickerData[row] as? String
    }


}

// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = mainPickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData as! String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blueColor()])
    return myTitle
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking an `Array`, create a `Dictionary` for you main datasource like this and use it properly to get `numberOfRowsInComponent` count and  `titleForRow`.

```
let dataDict:NSMutableDictionary = ["Area":["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"]
        ,"Energy":["Btus", "Calories", "Ergs", "Foot-Pounds", "Joules", "Kilogram-Calories", "Kilogram-Meters", "Kilowatt-Hours", "Newton-Meters", "Watt-Hours"]]
let mainPickerData = dataDict.allKeys;
let leftPickerData = dataDict.objectForKey("Energy"); //here you can pas the string return from pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) delegate for main picker

print(mainPickerData);
print(leftPickerData);
```

if you left and right picker is supposed to contain same data, you can use one data source for that.

Also in the delegate `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?`

don't check the tag on your picker instance, if you have already set tags for your pickers, then use the `pickerView` object in the method signature to check for tag.Do it like this

```
if pickerView.tag == 1 {...} 
else if (pickerView.tag == 2) {...}
```

The reason that data is showing same in all picker is that in your `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?`
 the condition is always true . i.e.  `mainPicker.tag == 1` , if you have set the tag 1 for mainPicker, hence it return same the data for all pickers.

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
 // The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    switch (pickerView.tag) {

    case mainPicker.tag:

        return mainPickerData.count

    case leftPicker.tag,rightPicker.tag:

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.objectForKey(mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        return leftRightPickerData.count;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}//F.E

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    switch (pickerView.tag) {

    case mainPicker.tag:

        return mainPickerData[row] as? String;

    case leftPicker.tag,rightPicker.tag:

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.objectForKey(mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        return leftRightPickerData[row] as? String;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return "";

}

// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
    if(pickerView.tag == 1 ){

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.objectForKey(mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        leftPicker.reloadAllComponents();
        rightPicker.reloadAllComponents();
    }
}
```

Above is the implementation for your `UIPickerView` `delegate` and `datasource`.
Write the following code in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
    dataDict = ["Area":["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"]
        ,"Energy":["Btus", "Calories", "Ergs", "Foot-Pounds", "Joules", "Kilogram-Calories", "Kilogram-Meters", "Kilowatt-Hours", "Newton-Meters", "Watt-Hours"]]
    mainPickerData = dataDict.allKeys;
    leftRightPickerData = dataDict.objectForKey(mainPickerData.firstObject as! String) as! NSArray
```

I just have added 2 key/value pair for your code, you can add rest of the values in `dataDict`.

Paste the following code in your class before `viewDidLoad()`

```
var dataDict:NSMutableDictionary!
var mainPickerData:NSArray!
var leftRightPickerData:NSArray!
```

Comment: Yes you alright regarding the left and right pickerview, they suppose have the same data. I'm sorry I have some questions for you...

1- How can I share the datasourse and delegate between the left and right pickerview. Should I remove the delegate and sourse from the mainpickerview.

2- let leftPickerData = dataDict.objectForKey("Energy"); 
What about the other groups, How can I add them in same variable. and shall I do the same for the right ??

3-

Comment: for your last comment regarding the tag, what should I do. Currently, nothing shows up in any of them.

Comment: Check my updated answer, hope it will solve your problem and on change row in your main picker view the left and right view will update accordingly

Comment: For adding other groups in dataDict  follow the same format i.e. "your key" : [ array for that key] , "yournextKey" :  [ array for that key]

Comment: I just wanna let you know that I linked the mainPicker, left, and right with datasourse and delegate. Also, I have given the mainPicker 0 tag, the left 1 tag, and the right 2 tag.

Regarding you updated solution, I have got unresolved error for the line :

leftRightPickerData = dataDict.objectForKey(mainPickerData.firstObject as! String) as! NSArray

when I add "let" before it, I got another error for  "dataDict" that says unresolved identifier.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it and remove the changes you have you have mentioned in your above comment.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your concern, I highly appreciate your time. 
Would you please check these two links that I got after I made the recommended changes.

http://s1.postimg.org/523f3smwf/Screen_Shot_2015_11_27_at_12_39_20_AM.png

http://s11.postimg.org/f5mf2tob7/111.png

Thank you in advance

Comment: Set the datasource and delegate for all the pickers

Comment: Done >>>> datasourse & delegate for all pickers.

Did you see the second image that shows the error ????

I posted two links .. ;)

Comment: yes i saw that, you still getting that error? Whats your Xcode version?

Comment: you still having that issue?

Comment: Yes I still have the issue ... 

check out the last update code :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966224/multiple-uipickerview-errors

Comment: Check the comment on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966224/multiple-uipickerview-errors